# Edit/change Windows file explorer default sorting and arrangement

Tags: windows, registry, explorer, windows-11

How to edit/change default options of Windows file explorer? Recently in some update of Windows 11 all the folders and files in the "Downloads" were changed to be viewed as "titles". And every folder's content in Downloads was arranged by "Date modified" which grinds my gears.

I want to set default options for file explorer. Sorting: by type (files first etc like it has been before), arrangement: none.

Screenshot of a folder with content sorted by Date Modified
[image: Screenshot of a folder with content sorted by Date Modified]

I've looked through Windows support and Youtube. Right now only option is to go through every folder individually and change the options manually.
StackOverflow has some similiar questions answered but they are outdated as they are from 7 years behind.

Comment: Something something registry shell bags

Answer (score 2):

Set everything how you want it to be in one folder, and then simply click on view>Options (so that the dropdown pops up)>Change folder and search options>view>apply to folders

This is for Windows 10, but should roughly mirror for Windows 11.

You would think it would only apply the settings you can toggle in the list below but that's not the case.